# only writing "return false" once to handle clicking on many links

Tags: javascript, refactoring, return

Instead of writing `return false;` many times is there a way to set a collection of links such that if any of them are clicked the click function would `return false;`? I'd still like to have most links `return true` so showing code that would `return true` vs. `return false` would be particularly appreciated.

The goal is writing less code. I'd also like to know if this is a bad idea for reason I can't understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simpliest method is binding one event listener to the document, and checking for the target: http://jsfiddle.net/gKZ7q/

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target.nodeName.toUpperCase() === 'A') e.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

- For anchors with nested elements, you have to add an additional loop:

  ```
  var targ = e.target;
  do {
      if (targ.nodeName.toUpperCase() === 'A') {
          e.preventDefault();
          break;
      }
  } while ((targ = targ.parentNode) !== document.documentElement);
  // document.body should be fine. Using document.documentElement in case
  // that a fool places an anchor outside the <body>
  ```
- Links can also be triggered through a key event.

Comment: thanks, but i'd still like to have many links `return true`. can you show we what the `if` condition would look like for that? I guess easiest would be ...`getElementsByClassName==='dontGoThere', yes/no?

Comment: `targ.nodeName.toUpperCase() === 'A'` can also be written as `/^a$/i.test((targ.nodeName)`

Comment: @KooiInc Yes, but the non-RegEx method is slightly faster.

Comment: @timpeterson `e.target` holds the link. Check for the value of the `href` attribute. E.g. `if (targ.href.substring(0,11) === 'javascript:') { .. prevent default ...}`, and `if (/^javascript:[\S\s]*?return\s+true;?\s*$/.test()) { ... do nothing ...}`

Comment: @RobW thanks, for completeness in your answer can you show what the HTML would look like for links that would `return true` **vs.** `return false`?